# Need equivalent for (non-existent) whereHour command in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I use the following SQL query to return a set of data (upcoming sessions):

```
SELECT * FROM availabilities 
WHERE 
name = "Booked"
and 
start_time >= (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
and
DAY(start_time) >= (DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
and
HOUR(start_time) = (HOUR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)));
```

This returns the data I need (upcoming sessions 24 hours in advance) but I am struggling to get this into a format that can return the same data in Laravel (using 5.3).

I have this as a start:

```
$UpcomingSessions = Availability::where('name', '=', 'booked')
->where("start_time",">=", '(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))')
->whereDay("start_time",">=", '(DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)))')
->where("start_time",">=", '(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR))')
->get();
```

But can't figure out what to do with the hour part as there is no

```
whereHour
```

in Laravel.

If I try:

```
->where("HOUR(start_time)",">=", '(HOUR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)))')
```

I get the following message:

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'HOUR(start_time)' in 'where clause'

Is there an equivalent command for whereHour that I could use perhaps? Any ideas on how to format the SQL correctly would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey what if you try to use https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

```
->where(DB:raw("HOUR(start_time) >= '(HOUR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)))'))
```

or

```
->whereRaw()
```

Comment: Thanks, whereRaw is doing the job.

Comment: @Ezequiel Fernandez
Code syntax is wrong please change it!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 8.x here.

From the Docs, there is a `whereTime()` function.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereTime('created_at', '=', '11:20:45')
            ->get();
```

The value given as the second parameter could be any formatted string. So you could, for instance, just narrow it down to 2 `whereTime()` calls:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereTime('created_at', '>=', '11:00:00')
            ->whereTime('created_at', '<', '12:00:00')
            ->get();
```

Comment: After trying and testing, found out that the time string must have 2-digit numbers for the hour, or it would get all 1 leading hours when checking for an hour like 1 and so on for the 2's. 
So if Interpolating a variable like `"$hour:00:00"`, It would be better and safer to use the `sprint()` function. E.g. `->whereTime('created_at', '>=', sprintf("%02d:00:00, $hour))` and `->whereTime('created_at', '<', sprintf("%02d:00:00, $hour + 1))` .